# Problems after updating BIOS (dual boot Win/Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, hp, 20.10

The **HP SoftPaq Download Manager** (running on Windows 10) offers me to update the BIOS to the 01.37, Rev. A  version which is stated as critical (my current version is 01.35). I hadn't face issues before when updating BIOS. However, since the last BIOS update, I've installed Ubuntu (on a separate SSD, GRUB is also there). On the web, many people notice that after updating BIOS they have trouble to boot to Ubuntu. So, I'd like to ask the community if it possible to do something in advance to prevent complications?
NB: I also posted this question on the official [HP forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-Notebooks/Problems-after-updating-BIOS-dual-boot-Win-Ubuntu/td-p/7901473) but didn't get any answer by now.

Comment: You will need to provide links or information about what exactly goes wrong. There is no "protect Ubuntu against BIOS update side effects" solution.

Comment: @Jos: I don't think this is a good answer. For instance, on windows you should switch off bitlocker biefore updating. So there indeed *could* be some possible preparations and it is better to ask BEFORE.

Comment: I think the "many people notice that ... they have trouble to boot" needed clarification. We need to know what exactly that trouble is, so we may possibly prevent it.

Comment: UEFI/BIOS update may change some settings back to defaults. And if you had to change some settings to install Ubuntu, you need to redo those settings. My old motherboard has multiple settings that I have to redo, but have not gotten any updates recently. And backups always required before any system change, but should be regular anyway. Windows updates normally change Windows back to first in boot order, just as grub should. But grub uses efibootmgr to change boot order & HP is just about the only system that does not seem to recognize those changes. You have to change in UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a BIOS update shouldn't pose a problem in a dual boot setup with Ubuntu and Windows. It is however generally a good idea to make sure you have up to date backups of your data on an external drive - just in case.

By the way, HP has started to distribute BIOS updates via [LVFS](https://fwupd.org/). Currently they aren't supporting many devices but if your device is supported ([check here](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/)) you'll even be able to update your BIOS from Ubuntu via the Software Center.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, my device is not in the list, so I'll try to update from Windows. I have good backups of the data and both systems, but my concern is about not able to _boot_ into Ubuntu.

Comment: As I wrote before, a BIOS update usually shouldn't break your system. If it does for some reason you can always boot from a USB disk and run boot-repair. Good luck with the update, let us know whether it worked out.